# Point charge in a five-dielectric medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dielectric

What is the electrostatic potential due to a point charge in a five-dielectric medium with planar interfaces?  Specifically, consider a system with planar interfaces, and the dielectric constants:
$$
\epsilon_1,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ z<-a \\
\epsilon_2,\ \ \  -a<z<-b \\
\epsilon_3,\ \ \ \ \ \  -b<z<b \\
\epsilon_4,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ b<z<a \\
\epsilon_5,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ z>a
$$

This is a generalization of the three-dielectric case treated in this [Am. J. Phys.](http://ajp.aapt.org/resource/1/ajpias/v46/i11/p1172_s1) from 1978.  Can it also be solved via image charges?

Comment: If you have access to that paper, it should contain all the necessary methods to answer this.

Comment: I have access to the paper, but the question is whether the same methods can be applied here.  I have never seen image charges applied to this many dielectric interfaces.  Is it as straightforward as adding an infinite series of images charges for _each_ interface?  Just curious if anyone on here had experience with this type of geometry.